# Angular - Multi Level Routing

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I want to do multi lvl routing:

For each lvl I have one view but dynamically changing data.

[image]

How can I do that and have my URLs like:

**host.com/laptop/laptop-list/apple/234-product**

Not like I have below:

**host.com/laptops/1/2/12-product**

And is that correct to pass ID between components? Or must I create a database service for all of it, if yes how can I do that with multiple APIs

**host.com/api/laptops**

**host.com/api/laptopProducts** and more more

...

I did this, (it's working) but it's passing my ID.

```
<a [routerLink]="laptop.id" *ngFor="let laptop of laptops">
```

component.ts

```
id = 0;

 constructor(private database: DatabaseService, private activeRoute: ActivatedRoute) { 
    this.activeRoute.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.id = parseInt(params["id"]);
    });
  }
```

component.html

```
<div *ngFor="let laptopProduct of laptopProducts">
            <div *ngIf="laptopProduct.laptopID === id">
                {{laptopProduct.name}}
            </div>
        </div>
```

Everything works good but I want name instead of ID in URLs

Comment: What if somebody passes the link off to somebody else? How will your component know the laptopID then?

Comment: laptopID is in JSON on /api/laptopProducts

Comment: My point is you can't really pass it behind the scenes because if someone goes to the link via a URL given to them it will not be passed behind the scenes from them. Assuming that your product names are unique you could take the name and look it up in your JSON data from /api/laptopProducts

Comment: I have one table with 2 records. Laptops and Apple Laptops , first id = 1, first id = 2, i have third table with laptopProducts, and one record with one to many relations is laptopID = 1, and when first table id === laptopID shows me these which pass the condition, and with id = 2 show me apple laptops is there any other way to not pass it with routerLink?

Answer (score 0):

create a dictionnary in your component :

```
var dict = []; // create an empty array
id;

constructor(private database: DatabaseService, private activeRoute: 
ActivatedRoute) { 

dict.push({
  key:   "1",
  value: "Apple"
});

this.activeRoute.params.subscribe(params => {
  this.id = dict[parseInt(params["id"])].value;
});
}
```

But, You shouldn't use the params to get this ID.. Use a service and share the id between your components.

Comment: But my view depends of my id, i have 7 sections and each of this have their own sections i need to transport using my id's, u think i need to create one service and share multiple id ? What when it repeat i mean, laptop.id = 1 and pc.id = 1 i need two variables for each of id's ?

Comment: What if you have 2 differents dictionnaries. One for laptop and another one for pc ? May be I don't get your issue.